# LNK1181 Linker error, cannot open input file, on Windows 10 -- spurious, then solved

Tags: windows, makefile, hyperlink, linker

I don't use visual studio -- just Make and command line.
My Makefile originally had

```
QT_LIB_DIR = C:\Qt\5.12.5\msvc2017_64\lib
```

with the link line containing

```
 /LIBPATH:$(QT_LIB_DIR)
```

This resulted in the link error.  The fix was simply to put quotes around the folder name:

```
QT_LIB_DIR = "C:\Qt\5.12.5\msvc2017_64\lib"
```

This is odd for various reasons:

1) The file separators are all back slashes.
2) There is no white space in the name.
3) When I copy and pasted the original command resulting from Make into a cmd.exe window, the link succeeded, even though the failing make command and successful pasted command are identical on the screen.

Is Make inserting some odd non-visible characters to the command line, but copy and paste turned them into harmless white space?  Do the quotes cause Link to be more careful?

Comment: Maybe your make is not invoking cmd.exe.  Maybe it's running a POSIX shell instead.  In that case, the backslashes will be considered escape characters by the shell and removed.  In general it's better to always use forward slashes in makefiles.  Most Windows commands accept both.

Comment: I bet that is it.  I am using the bash shell from msys2.  Thank you!